# How does the Rust `String` type/`read_line` function know how much memory is needed without explicitly being told?

Tags: memory, input, memory-management, rust, io

In C, before using the `scanf` or `gets` "stdio.h" functions to get and store user input, the programmer has to manually allocate memory for the data that's read to be stored in. In Rust, the `std::io::Stdin.read_line` function can seemingly be used without the programmer having to manually allocate memory prior. All it needs is for there to be a mutable `String` variable to store the data it reads in. How does it do this seemingly without knowledge about how much memory will be required?

Comment: `String`s can dynamically resize their internal buffer.

Comment: @pretzelhammer What's an internal buffer, and how does `String` know how much to resize it by?

Comment: [A `String` is just a `Vec<u8>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#278-280) and [`Vec` makes the following guarantees](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees).

Comment: @nicoty `read_line` starts with a fixed size and resizes the `String` as needed until the whole line has been consumed. Equivalent functionality can be [implemented in C](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) as well, it's not unique to Rust.

Comment: I see. Thanks for all the links and clarifications, they've helped me gain a better understanding on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want a detailed explanation, you can dig a bit into the [`read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) method which is part of the [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) trait. Heavily simplified, the function look like this.

```rust
fn read_line(&mut self, target: &mut String)
    loop {
        // That method fills the internal buffer of the reader (here stdin)
        // and returns a slice reference to whatever part of the buffer was filled.
        // That buffer is actually what you need to allocate in advance in C.
        let available = self.fill_buf();

        match memchr(b'\n', available) {
            Some(i) => {
                // A '\n' was found, we can extend the string and return.
                target.push_str(&available[..=i]);
                return;
            }
            None => {
                // No '\n' found, we just have to extend the string.
                target.push_str(available);
            },
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, that method extends the string as long as it does not find a `\n` character in `stdin`.

If you want to allocate a bit of memory in advance for the `String` that you pass to `read_line`, you can create it using [`String::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.with_capacity). This will not prevent the `String` to reallocate if it is not large enough though.